# Formula to classify multiple, specific values in a range using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I could be doing this completely wrong, or I could be on the right path, I have no idea! I'm trying to grade a decision based on 3 criteria. The grades are AAA-A and BBB-B, etc. but for now I just need AAA-A and can figure out the rest.

Essentially, we want Col. J to populate based on what Col.'s G-I say. In my head it's super easy but I want to automate this step.

So I start with col.I and see the pairing.. AAA-A results are any of these "G/G" "LG/G" "G/LG" or "R/R". If it is one of those 4 pairings then we start at AA grade.

Then I check col.G (it doesnt matter now if I check H or G first), and if G>=.5 we grade it higher at AAA, if its less than .5 then do nothing and keep it at AA.

Then I look at col. H (or G if we started at H) and if it is a "Y" we grade down from AA to A. or AAA to AA. But it is "N" do nothing.

What I have so far is attached. It technically works for 3/4 of these cells but that could be a coincidence. The results column(J) should be row3 - AA, row4 - AA, row5 - AAA, row6 - AA.

And for one additional test, imagine: col.g = .64, col.h = Y, col.i = G/G -- then we want AA as the result.

Definitely the hardest test I've had in excel/sheets. I appreciate the help! Thanks in advance!

Formula I tried:

```
=Ifs((or(I3="G/G",I3="LG/G",I3="G/LG",I3="R/R"),"AA", and(or(I3="G/G",I3="LG/G",I3="G/LG",I3="R/R"),G3>0.5),"AAA",H3="Y","A")
```

Data Sample:

|  | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | -0.07 | N | R/R | AA |
| 4 | -0.46 | N | R/R | AA |
| 5 | 0.64 | N | G/G | AA |
| 6 | 0.76 | Y | LG/G | AA |

Comment: It's generally frowned on here to post code as an image. As doing that means anyone wanting to help you, has to type out your code (versus a simple copy and paste). Likewise, tables are best presented a tables (not images) for the same reason. Suggest, when posting a question, take a gander at `?` (help). The how-to's are all well explained. :)

Answer (score 0):

As presented, your formula simply returns an error, and seems like a misinterpretation of how `Ifs` works. However, it suggest you're trying to `Nest` `If` statements. And, from your description, I think that makes sense.

Assuming that's a valid interpretation, the following does what you want.
(At least as far as `AAA-A` is concerned).

```
=If(or(I3="G/G",I3="LG/G",I3="G/LG",I3="R/R"),if(G3<0.5,"AA","AAA"),if(H3="Y","A","Not an A"))
```

The `BBB-B` logic would be the same (just nested in where `"Not an A"` is).